# Portable HTML5 local storage

Tags: storage, local, html5, persistence

I've been developing client-side applications using HTML and Javascript, and I've been trying to find a way to automatically save local storage data to a flash drive or other storage device. Is it possible to save the local storage for an HTML document on a USB flash drive (instead of in the browser cache) so that the web page with the locally stored data can be accessed anywhere, or sent as an email attachment? If not, is there another way to keep persistent data for a specific web page on a flash drive?

Also, I'd like the local storage to be portable across web browsers, instead of depending on a specific (portable) web browser installation (so that all the local storage data won't depend on that specific installation of the web browser.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you are a client-side developer, I assume that you are creating the applications that you want locally-stored (or at least you have access to the code for them).

If that is the case, then you probably should be looking at dojo-storage: http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2008/03/dojo-storage.html

Edit: I did not read the question carefully enough; the requirements that the locally stored info be accessible across different browsers and be transferrable via E-mail are essentially giving the locally stored data first-class status; something that you don't get from dojox storage nor html5 storage nor html5 offline mode.

The only idea that pops into my mind is to do something like what TiddlyWiki does, and dynamically modify the source of the page itself; but even then it would be the responsibility of the user to manually save the page periodically.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit vague; I don't know if you are asking this as a browser end-user or as w web developer.

Assuming user, I would say use Firefox, install a portable version of FF on your flash drive, & create a new profile, with the target folder on your flash drive as well, then delete the default so your new default is the one stored on the flash.  This way, all your bookmarks, cache, storage, etc is on that flash.
http://duckduckgo.com/?q=firefox+different+drive+profile

Comment: That would be one way to approach the problem, but it wasn't what I was looking for. Is there a way to make the HTML 5 local storage portable across multiple web browsers?

Comment: I'm looking for some way to maintain the local storage data alongside the document without needing to store it in a browser cache. Sending an entire web browser installation as an email attachment would be an unwieldy solution; I just want to store the document and the local storage together in one location.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be feasible to synchronize the local storage data across two different web browsers, but I don't know of any browser extensions that would accomplish this.